# Refreshing the DataGridView without having to restart my program

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a problem with refreshing DataGridView.

I open `Form2` from `Form1`, in `Form2` I add new record and close `Form2`, when I'm back to Form1 where DataGridView is, there are no changes. :(

If I close program and run it again, new records are there.

How to refresh DataGridView when I close Form2, so when I go back to Form1 there are updated records?

Here is my sample code:

```
Form1 = window with dataviewgrid + 1 button (ADD NEW)

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 okno2;
        okno2 = new Form2();
        okno2.Show();
    }
```

Form2:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\ja\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_imie.Text !="" & txt_nazwisko.Text !="" & txt_adres.Text !="")
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tabelka1 (imie,nazwisko,adres) values ('"+txt_imie.Text+"','"+txt_nazwisko.Text+"','"+txt_adres.Text+"' )"; 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Record added");
                cmd.CommandText = "refresh";
                cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also add the code that how are you loading your GridView

Answer (score 1):

Implement the formClosed event of Form2 then you can refresh your datagridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 okno2;
    okno2 = new Form2();
    okno2.Show();
   form2.FormClosed += Form2OnFormClosed;

}

  private void Form2OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs args)
    {
      // Code for refreshing
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget form closing can be cancelled

Comment: The formclosing event is called also when form2 is cancelled.

Comment: Can't get you! It is not necessary to `Refresh` when Closing is cancelled right?

Comment: Thats true, you must check if the args are not cancelled. Thanks!

Comment: This one also wrong. FormClosing can be cancelled in next `EventHandler` too isn't it?

Comment: I dont get you now, what do you mean? I agree when you cancel the form2 (DialogResult.Cancel) you must not refresh the datagrid. But what do you mean by the FormClosing event can be cancelled? MSDN: ' Canceling the FormClosing event of an MDI child form does not prevent the FormClosing event of the MDI parent form from being raised. However, canceling the event will set to true the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs class that is passed as a parameter to the parent form. To force all MDI parent and child forms to close, set the Cancel property to false in the MDI parent form.'

Comment: You subscribed `FormClosing' and checking `args.Cancel` consider no body has cancelled yet, consider some other piece of code also subscribed for `FormClosing' event which will be executed immediately after your `FormClosing Handler` what if `args.Cancel` set to `true` in that event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34318/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-sriram-sakthivel)

Comment: It is more stable to use FormClosed, i've updated the code example.